# Removing Null Values and Slicing Results

Tags: arcgis-desktop, labeling, null

I am attempting to label features that can have multiple combinations of codes. The label is based off of three fields *([DescriptionA], [DescriptionB], [DescriptionC]).*

I'd like to create a python expression to remove all null values from the labels, and to remove a section from the end of each returned value.

(Ex. 10QR, 15QR)

Here is the code I have come up with based on a similar thread I've read:

```
    def FindLabel ( [DescriptionA], [DescriptionB], [DescriptionC] ):
return def FindLabel ( [DescriptionA], [DescriptionB], [DescriptionC] ):
if not ([DescriptionC] is None):
    return [DescriptionC]  .lstrip('Fuse-')
elif not([DescriptionB] is None):
    return [DescriptionB]  .lstrip('Fuse-') + '\n' + [DescriptionA]   .lstrip('Fuse-')
elif not([DescriptionA] AND [DescriptionB]  AND [DescriptionC]  is None):
    return [DescriptionA]  .lstrip('Fuse-') + '\n' + [DescriptionB]   .lstrip('Fuse-') + '\n' + [DescriptionC]   .lstrip('Fuse-')
else:
    return [DescriptionA]  .lstrip('Fuse-')
```

When I verify, it returns a syntax error message. I am sure there is more wrong to it than that. How should I proceed?

Answer (score 1):

There's a few things wrong with your script:

- First *indentation*, all lines post the def statement should be indented - python uses indentation for code levels; I'll assume that when you pasted into your question the indentation went funny otherwise you would have got an 'inconsistent indent' error rather than a syntax error.
- Your first line returns the function. You should never see `return def` together. `return` ends a function and `def` starts one which would confuse the parser and is most likely to be where you're getting a syntax error.
- You have multiple `return` statements, when you call `return` that is *the end* of your function, no more lines of code will be evaluated! *Finished! All done.* The way the logic flows you will return `[DescriptionC]` and nothing else if the field is not null. I would suggest building a list of the values (if not Null) and then returning on the last line (see example) but you could also build a string and return that, the key is do all the work and then `return` only when you're sure there's *nothing else that could possibly be done*.
- You have a space between description and `.lstrip`, while this will not stop the code from working it makes it very hard to read.

I believe you're after something like this:

```
def FindLabel ( [DescriptionA], [DescriptionB], [DescriptionC] ):
    rVal = [] # empty return list

    # if any values aren't null add them to the return list, str() isn't neccesary 
    # because the values passed to this function are always strings but for
    # clarity I'm showing that this only works for strings.
    if [DescriptionA] != None:
        rVal.append(str([DescriptionA])) # add lstrip if needed
    if [DescriptionB] != None:           # to these append statements
        rVal.append(str([DescriptionB])) # rVal.append(str([field]).lstrip('string'))
    if [DescriptionC] != None:
        rVal.append(str([DescriptionB]))

    if len(rVal) == 0:
        return '' # empty string, all 3 fields are null
    else:
        return '({})'.format(', '.join(rVal)) # return in format '(A, B, C)' only works on string lists
```